# 2 way SSL authentication failure when calling External web service from java WS client

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere, ssl-certificate

I need to create a Java based XML web service client which is deployed in IBM WAS server which calls web service hosted by external system. Here 2 way ssl authentication mechanism should be there.

Configuration team has already set up the below things in quality environment of client and web service appservers:

At WAS server in which my web service client exists:

1. server certificate in the trustStore
2. client certificate is available in the keystore

At App server in which actual WebService exists:

1. server certificate in the keyStore
2. client certificate is available in the trust store

**Coding:**
we Auto generated classes using WSDL file provided by WS provider.

called the WS method normally like there is no 2 way ssl authentication mechanism in place.

**problem:** we are getting a connection exception when calling web service method from WS Client.Seems we have trouble with the 2 way ssl mechanism.

**Full StackTrace Image as requested:**
[image]

Assumptions:
we assumed that the entire **handshake process** of 2 way SSL process happens **automatically** when the web service call is done normally from the client.

**Queries:**

1. Is our assumption correct that entire handshake process happens
   automatically here especially client sending its certificate ?
2. Do we need to specify at code level in java any details of path of
   trust Store or KeyStore before calling the web service method to enable client to send its certificate ?
3. If Yes for Qn 2 do we need to set below properties in code as mentioned in some reference links
       before calling WS method in client:

   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/to/your/key");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "your-keystore-    password");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path/to/your/trust/keystore");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "your-truststore-password");

Any suggestions/advice are highly welcome as we are stuck with this since few days.Its the first time we are working on web services which need 2 way SSL.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the connection exception? The only way to verify the SSL handshake completes successfully is to use a tool like tcpdump or iptrace to capture the network packets and generate a pcap file and view it in Wireshark (or use Wireshark to capture the pcap).

Comment: Hi  @AlexandrePolozoff  Thanks for replying.. Have added the image of Full Stack trace.

Comment: You will need to ensure that the right certificate is present to the target server when you try mutual authentication from WAS. Please see my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40863087/6216002 . In addition, make sure that your TLS protocol versions are matched.

Comment: You have to ensure that server part (you didnt write what kind of app server you have) is set to require SSL client certificate. You should set it up somewhere in SSL config of the server. The easiest way to check if it is actually enforced is to access via browser and see if you will be prompted for client cert.

Comment: Actually, you can also use tracing to try and debug this. Use the trace string *=info : SSL=all as specified at this link https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162961